# Limit 100 maximum characters in a div and generate read more button when exceed in css or js

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my existing work. I made it to limit the characters up to 30 but how would I add a read more link to my other page dynamically when characters exceed the limit? i need your help guys.

```
var myDiv = $('.wwdtext');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,30))

<div style="background-color:#FF6201;width:220px;height:220px">
    <div class="wwdtext">Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tell us about your attempts?

Comment: and you found nothing about this on Google ??

Comment: Why tag jQuery if you use pure JS?

Comment: I don't know if it works more easier in jquery?

Comment: `truncated = truncated.substr(0,maxLength) + '<span class="more">...</span><span style="display:none">'+truncated.substr(maxLength)+'</span>';` - now wire up class more to show next sibling

Comment: i have updates.. pls look and pls help. :(

Comment: is it like this? var myDiv = $('.wwdtext');
truncated = truncated.substr(0,50) + '<span class="more">...</span><span style="display:none">'+truncated.substr(50)+'</span>';

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/8ado5qzr/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myDiv = $('.wwdtext');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,100))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:#FF6201;width:220px;height:220px">
    <div class="wwdtext">Hello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldeqwrewqjkfbsajHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldeqwrewqjkfbsajHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello WorldHello Worldeqwrewqjkfbsaj</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do i get a button with that?

Comment: I need to have a read more link or button  when it exceeds the character limit.

Comment: @user3117337 add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before `</body>` tag , also add `<script>var myDiv = $('.wwdtext');
myDiv.text(myDiv.text().substring(0,100));</script>`

Comment: I tried this on jsfiddle but still doesnt generate the button.

Comment: I need to dynamically add a button when it exceeds the limit.. plss heeelp

Comment: did you find the solution?